# Reset identity Column to start from 1, where identity_columns.last_value is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran `DBCC` command on 100+ tables to reset the identity value where most of the tables were in the state where not even single record was inserted after creating the table.

So after running

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('{tableName}', RESEED, 0)
```

on tables, it set `identity_columns.last_value` to `null` in all new tables, due which when I'm inserting new record, identity column start from `0` instead of `1`.

I can insert one record and delete it to fix the issue, how can I fix for all tables at once.

This is the query that returns all the tables where  `identity_columns.last_value` is `null`

```
SELECT
    tables.name As TableName,
    identity_columns.last_value
FROM  
    sys.tables tables 
JOIN 
    sys.identity_columns identity_columns ON tables.object_id = identity_columns.object_id
WHERE 
    identity_columns.last_value IS NULL
```

Comment: Using _transact sql_. You must create a cursor and loop over them calling your `DBCC` command for each iteration. In addition, the `0` in your `DBCC` command refers to the start value for the first identity assignation.

Comment: @JaimeDrq can you plese write that as answer.
I'm not fully familiar with cursor.
Thank  you !

Comment: How did you run your original DBCC command 100+ times?

Comment: I did that using C#  (DbCommand) by getting all tha table  form DbContext.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test it, but something like this must work...

**SQL**

```
declare tableName varchar(100)

declare cur cursor for  
SELECT  
  tables.name As TableName
FROM sys.tables tables 
  JOIN sys.identity_columns identity_columns 
    ON tables.object_id=identity_columns.object_id
WHERE identity_columns.last_value IS NULL

open cur
fetch next from cur into @tableName

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  DBCC CHECKIDENT (@tableName, RESEED, 1)
  fetch next from cur into @tableName 
end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: I ran the above sql but I'm getting this in the message.
`Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL'
`
and `identity_columns.last_value` is still `null` for all the tables.

Comment: Yes, it's the message returned by the `DBCC`, each time you call it to reset the identity value. If you execute it manually, you are going to get the same message individually. You can add a `print @tableName` if you want to identify each message with its related table

Comment: Yes ,but this does not work.
`DBCC CHECKIDENT (@tableName, RESEED, 1)`
after running this I see `identity_columns.last_value` is null.

I tried this just by running on one  table manually.

Comment: This is because the `DBCC` works differently with truncated tables. If it's your case, read the Microsoft documentation to know how to use the `DBCC` arguments for each case. When you know it, you can add your extra conditions inside the `begin`/`end` blocks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Is there any way to fix this for the old tables ?
I will look  into it.
Thank you !